# Dagster failure notification systems

Tags: sentry, dagster

Is there a way in dagster to receive notifications when certain events occur, such as failures? For example, is there an integration with a tool like sentry available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [datadog integration](https://docs.dagster.io/docs/apidocs/libraries/dagster_datadog#dagster_datadog.datadog_resource) that lets users send events to datadog. From the docs:

```
@solid(required_resource_keys={'datadog'})
def datadog_solid(context):
    dd = context.resources.datadog

    dd.event('Man down!', 'This server needs assistance.')
    dd.gauge('users.online', 1001, tags=["protocol:http"])
    dd.increment('page.views')
    dd.decrement('page.views')
    dd.histogram('album.photo.count', 26, tags=["gender:female"])
    dd.distribution('album.photo.count', 26, tags=["color:blue"])
    dd.set('visitors.uniques', 999, tags=["browser:ie"])
    dd.service_check('svc.check_name', dd.WARNING)
    dd.timing("query.response.time", 1234)

    # Use timed decorator
    @dd.timed('run_fn')
    def run_fn():
        pass

    run_fn()

@pipeline(mode_defs=[ModeDefinition(resource_defs={'datadog': datadog_resource})])
def dd_pipeline():
    datadog_solid()

result = execute_pipeline(
    dd_pipeline,
    {'resources': {'datadog': {'config': {'api_key': 'YOUR_KEY', 'app_key': 'YOUR_KEY'}}}},
)
```

Adding first class user-configurable hooks for certain events (ie failure) is currently work in progress.

Comment: I see, so the notifications happen at the solid level. And for example just to monitor pipelines failing we should implement this kind of integration for each solid?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this simply was not available yet when the accepted answer was written, but the current Dagster version (0.9.16) has a better mechanism to solve the question at hand.

They now have a [hook system](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/hooks), where you can annotate a function to be triggered when either a pipeline has completed successfully or when it has failed.

Code example from the documentation:

```
@success_hook(required_resource_keys={'slack'})
def slack_on_success(context):
    message = 'solid {} succeeded'.format(context.solid.name)
    context.resources.slack.send_message(message)

@success_hook
def do_something_on_success(context):
    do_something()
```